# Linkedin API for full profile access

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I want to access the full LinkedIn profile information using the API, but I have only managed to access the basic profile and e-mail address with the API-key and Secret Key.

Am I missing something or is it more restricted in some manner?

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the LinkedIn API ?
Did you applied for partnership because as far as I know LinkedIn changed the policy of API , so the API will be available only through the partnership and for that you've to pay different fee based on partner program

Have a look here, the same thins we've too.
I've fulfilled the application 3 weeks ago but no response yet.

***Subject: Having acces on LinkedIn API [160721-001958]****

I had spoken with one of our experts on this and he had confirmed for me that you can still go through other workarounds for this.

1. Go to https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs
2. Click on either of the options based on your need. You will be directed to another page where if you scroll down you will find the button for Apply to become a LinkedIn Solutions Partner. Click on that.
3. You will be directed to a page that says Apply to become a LinkedIn Partner and you can fill up the form from there for access.

Comment: I got my linked in api from https://developer.linkedin.com/.Yes i have also applied for partnership but its 15 days iand i did not get any response.